# How to compute the value for $\mu$ for Normal Random Variable from the given probabilistic relation

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

**Q. Let $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma_2^2)$ be independent random variables such that**

**$P[$2X+4Y$ \leq 10] + P[$3X+Y$ \leq 9] = 1$**

**$P[$2X-4Y$ \leq 6] + P[$-3X+Y$ \geq 1] = 1$**

How do I compute the value for $\mu$?

My approach was to assume 4 Normal random variables $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ as ($2X+4Y$), ($3X+Y$), ($2X-4Y$) and ($-3X+Y$) respectively and then calculate Mean and variance for each of them in given variables.

Then converting the given relation for a **standard normal random variable** by subtracting with respective mean values and dividing with standard deviation both sides of the inequality so I can figure out values from the table.

Now I wanted to know if there any relation between let's say for example two random variable when the sum of their individual probabilities is $1$.

$\mu_A = 2\mu_X + 4\mu_Y = 6\mu$

$\mu_B = 4\mu$

$\mu_C = -2\mu$

$\mu_D = -2\mu$

```
Similarly calculating VARIANCE for each variable:
```

$\sigma_A = \sqrt[]{(2^2\sigma_1^2 + 4^2\sigma_2^2)}$ and so for others..

$P[\frac{A-\mu_A}{\sigma_A} \leq \frac{10-\mu_A}{\sigma_A}] + P[\frac{B-\mu_B}{\sigma_B} \leq \frac{9-\mu_A}{\sigma_B}] = 1 $

$P[ z \leq \frac{10-\mu_A}{\sigma_A}] + P[z \leq \frac{9-\mu_A}{\sigma_B}] = 1 $

How to proceed?

Comment: Please replace 'pictures' by JaX.

Comment: @BruceET done sir :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a normal random variable $W$ with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, the probability of the event $(W \leq \alpha)$ can be expressed in terms of $\Phi(\cdot)$, the CDF of a standard normal random variable as
$$P(W \leq \alpha) = \Phi\left( \frac{\alpha-\mu}{\sigma}\right).$$ Now, an important property of $\Phi(\cdot)$ is that
$$\Phi(\alpha) + \Phi(\beta) = 1 \iff \alpha + \beta = 0.$$
I hope that you will have discovered as part of your "so for others" that
$\sigma_C = \sigma_A$ and $\sigma_D = \sigma_B$.  So, use these to get two different expressions for $\mu$ in terms of $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ and hence in terms of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.